# Numerical evaluation of predictive likelihood

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, posterior, model-evaluation

I want to evaluate to predictive models based on their predictive likelihood. In a standard framework I would proceed as follows:
The two models predict $y_{t+1}$, whereas model one is based on assumption

$$y _t \sim \Pi_1(y_t |\Theta_1)$$
and model two is similar with a different set of parameters
$$y _t \sim \Pi_2(y_t |\Theta_2)$$
Bayesian estimation helps me to compute the posterior distribution of the parameters given observed data $D=(y_1,\ldots,y_t)$ by computing
$$\pi(\Theta_1|D) \text{ and } \pi(\Theta_2|D)$$
After observing $y_{t+1}$ I could evaluate 
$$\Pi_i (y_{t+1}|\Theta,D)$$
for the two models and check which model returned the highest score.

However, I am faced to the problem that in my case I am interested in $z_{t+1}= f(y_{t+1})$, and this functional $f ()$ does not allow me to evaluate the likelihood at $\Theta$. Is there a suitable (and accepted) way to generate draws from the posterior predictive distribution of $z_{t+1}$ and in a next step compare the (empirical) distribution function of the sampled $z_{t+1}$ with the observed realization?

Comment: What about: simulate theta from the posterior, then simulate y_{t+1} from the model given D and theta drawn previously, and then take z_t+1 = f(y_t+1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you observe $y_{t+1}$, you can evaluate $z_{t+1}=f(y_{t+1})$ either analytically or numerically and compare this value (assuming it is a real number) with the predictive distribution of $z_{t+1}$ which is given by the predictive density
$$g_i(z_{t+1}|D) = \int_{\Theta} \Pi_i(\theta|D)\Pi_i(z_{t+1}|\theta,D)\text{d}\theta$$
where $\Pi_i(z_{t+1}|\theta,D)$ denotes the conditional distribution of $z_{t+1}$ given the past and the value $\theta$ of the parameter. It is also the distribution of the transform by $f$ of $Y_{t+1}\sim \Pi_i(y_{t+1}|\theta,D)$. If this distribution is not analytically available, a way to simulate from it is as follows:

1. Generate $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_N\sim\Pi_i(\theta|D)$
2. Generate $y_{t+1}^1\sim\Pi_i(y_{t+1}|\theta_1,D)$,..., $y_{t+1}^N\sim\Pi_i(y_{t+1}|\theta_N,D)$
3. Compute $z_{t+1}^1=f(y_{t+1}^1)$,..., $z_{t+1}^N=f(y_{t+1}^N)$